# Open PDF on Nougat

Tags: android, pdf, android-7.0-nougat

I have a file path: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/rocks.v**d**.*****.develop/files/1Q 2017 financial results.pdf

this is code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    try {
        String newFilePath = filePath.replaceAll("%20", " ");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(newFilePath), "application/pdf");
        } else {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(newFilePath);
            File file = new File(uri.getPath());
            if (file.exists()){
                uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
                intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            }
        }

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        context.startActivity(intent);
```

My uri = content://rocks.v**d**.*****.develop.provider/files/Android/data/rocks.v**d**.*****.develop/files/1Q%202017%20financial%20results.pdf

Pdf reader is opening with Unexpected error.
Whats wrong?

Comment: is the problem only in nougat devices?

Comment: @Anmol yeah, only nougat

Comment: @Anmol thank you man, i found a bug:
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

flag READ_URI_PERM was replaced by NO_HISTORY ))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

Here you are wiping out all your existing flags, notably your `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`. As a result, the activity that you start will not have access to your content.

Switch from `setFlags()` to `addFlags()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried this one but still not work. Can you give me any suggestion or full code?

Comment: @Passionate.C: I do not know what "still not work" means. I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve] and explain **in detail** ***exactly*** what your problem is.

Comment: @CommonsWare I posted new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48103496/xamarin-android-open-file-using-default-app-not-work-only-android-7-or-above Can you please check it and help me?

Answer (score 3):

If You Are Using android-N (i.e API 24 Above) Do Like this

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    File f = new File(Your File Path);

    Uri uri = null;


    // So you have to use Provider
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);

        // Add in case of if We get Uri from fileProvider.
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    }else{
        uri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    }

    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    startActivity(intent);
} catch(Exeption e){
    e.printstacktrace();
}
```

you Can also use this code above Lollipop.

Answer (score -1):

opening it in Adobe pdf reader. If adobe reader is not installed i am redirecting to google play.

```
 private void viewPdf(Uri file){
Intent intent;
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(file, "application/pdf");
try{
startActivity(intent);
}catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
builder.setTitle("No Application Found");
builder.setMessage("Download from Android Market?");
builder.setPositiveButton("Yes, Please", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
marketIntent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.adobe.reader"));
startActivity(marketIntent);

}
});
builder.setNegativeButton("No, Thanks", null);
builder.create().show();

}
```

Comment: i have this blocks(

Comment: is there any error in your log? or in which application you are trying to open your pdf in?

Comment: no, i have not any errors. 2 free PDF Readers. I try it on emulator

Comment: if we need any permissions?

Comment: if i can setup adobe on emulator?

Comment: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.adobe.reader }

Comment: @Anmol: This code will not work on Android 7.0+ devices. Your code is correct if the `Uri` has a `file` scheme, but you cannot use that on Android 7.0+. If the `Uri` has a `content` scheme, such as from `FIleProvider`, you are not adding `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to the `Intent`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the advise, by mistake i provided him the old code, which is not updated for nougat yet.